# Modification of my Scottish Clan Motto (luceo non uro)

Tags: english-to-latin-translation, motto, new-latin

I am in the process of planning out a tattoo, and I want to get my family's clan motto. The [Mackenzie Clan](https://www.scotsconnection.com/clan_crests/mackenzie.htm) motto is

> Luceo Non Uro

Which as I understand translates to **"shine not burn."** That said, however, the source I linked says that it translates to "I shine not burn." I am rather unfamiliar with the Latin language, so my question(s) are the following;

1. Is it necessary to modify the Latin phrase for it to translate to "**I** shine not burn," or is the "I" implied/part of the phrase?
2. If modification is required, what would the new Latin phrase be?

Comment: In what context is it used exactly?

Comment: @JohanVanhove What do you mean? It is a motto.

Comment: This is also Clan McLeod's Motto which translates "I Shine, Yet I do not Burn"

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The direct translation of "luceo non uro" is "I shine; I do not burn."

The "I" part is directly stated as part of the grammar. If you take the verb base luce- and add the -o ending, this means that the 'doer' of the verb is 'I.' This process of affixing endings to verbs is called conjugation.

If you wanted to get a different meaning across with the motto -- for example if you wanted to tell somebody to follow the motto -- you would add a different ending. "Luce non ure" would be "shine; don't burn."

In short, this motto doesn't need any changes for it to mean what you want it to mean.

Comment: Just to clarify: generally you wouldn't want to put *non* alone with an imperative. You'd probably do something like "noli urere" or "ne uras" if you wanted to say, "Don't burn."